# Is there a widget or a library recommended for making this kind of TimePicker?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[image: DatePicker]

This is exactly what I want it to look like. But how can I make it? I don't know if I can get this result with a ListView and a ScrollController since I need to be able to loop through the seconds and minutes and I also want it to start at the 00:30 position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `CupertinoPicker`

```dart
Container(
    color: Colors.grey.shade100,
    width: 100,
    height: 200,
    child: CupertinoPicker(
      itemExtent: 48,
      onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {},
      children: List.generate(
        12,
        (index) => Center(
          child: Text(
            index.toString(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```